# Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on Nextjs/Reactjs i am fetching data after click on button but in my console i am getting following error

```
Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop
```

Here is my current code ( data is displaying with id and title)(

```
<button onClick={fetchReviewsFromServer}>Load Reviews From Server</button>
                        {
                            reviewfromserver.map(reviewnew=>{
                                return(
                                    <>
                                       <div key={reviewnew.id}> // not working
                                            <div>{reviewnew.id}- {reviewnew.title} </div>
                                       </div>

                                    </>
                                )
                            })
                        }
```

Comment: Since you just have 1 node, you do not have to wrap it in Fragment`<></>`

Comment: It needs to be on the **outermost** tag, in this case that's the fragment. However, in this case you don't need the fragment since there's only one child, so you can remove the fragment. If you wanted to use the fragment cos you're adding more children later for example, replace the empty tag fragment with `<React.Fragment key={reviewnew.id}>`

Comment: Have a look at the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43892905/4989208 to understand more about the key prop. Try removing the fragment wrapping your component, and ensure that the ids are unique for all the elements in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The child in your list is the empty `<>` element, I don't see a need for it regardless, since you only have one child element *to that element*.

```js
<button onClick={fetchReviewsFromServer}>Load Reviews From Server</button>
{
    reviewfromserver.map(reviewnew=>{
        return(
            <div key={reviewnew.id}> // not working
                <div>{reviewnew.id}- {reviewnew.title} </div>
            </div>
        )
    })
}
```

Comment: While not necessary here, If OP did need to use a fragment as the outer element, they would have to avoid the shorthand `<>...</>` and instead use the longhand equivalent `<React.Fragment key={keyVal}>...</React.Fragment>` in order to supply it with a `key` prop.

Comment: @Nora Soderlund : i have to remove<></> because right now i have one child element otherwise code is okay/fine , am i right ?

Comment: Kind of? The issue is that you're not setting the key property as the outer element's property. **Removing the fragment element does resolve it, yes,** because then the outer element (the list child) becomes your `div`.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the fragmets are items. Remove them, you don't need them anyway.